# Phonegap is not able to find project directory

Tags: cordova

I installed PhoneGap 3.4 using npm on OSX using `sudo npm install -g phonegap`. I'm trying to start my project, so I created the project `phonegap create myapp testing.myapp MyApp`, and then `cd mypp`.

Whenever I write anything related to the newly created project (build, run, etc ...) it complains with `[error] project directory could not be found`.

Any ideas? I searched around but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: You mean `cd myapp` right? Strange, it's how it supposed to work. Maybe try to install also the cordova CLI?

Comment: @QuickFix yeah, that's what I ended up doing :-\. I don't quite understand why it wouldn't work as I was following the exact steps from their official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Is there the .cordova file under the project directory?
If not, you just create the file, then the problem should be resolved.

```
$> cd MyApp
$> touch .cordova
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Any idea why .cordova is not created by default? It makes no sense -_-